# LARAVEL GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: database, laravel

I have an SQL query that shows the list of the projects. There's a button next to each project that shows the notes attached to them. I attached the 'notes table' to the 'projects table'  and I used GROUP_CONCAT, which makes possible that each project can have more notes attached to them. My problem is, that if I don't add note to a project at all, the project doesn't appear on the list.

Thanks for the help!

Query:

```
 $projects =DB::table('projects')->join('projects_notes', 'projects_notes.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')->select('projects.*', DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(projects_notes.note SEPARATOR ', ') as note"))->groupBy('projects.id')->get();
```

Comment: You might want to call `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` so you can manually test the query. It'll likely give you a better idea of what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `leftjoin()` instead of `join()`.